# Expandable database design

Tags: database-design

I have a back-end system. It needs to unify all the games(game 1, game 2, game 3, etc)
My initial design is:

one centralized user DB (user-ID and game type is here), and each game resides on its own DB(game type to user-ID tagging is here)

however the db has to be in one since chose hosting server, due to budget constraint at the moment. Could be expand in the future(meant each game has its own user DB, though again, user management will be another issue of duplication).

Any idea of What's the suitable design to Expand the user management module, with changes minimized?

Comment: Let me see if I understand (and I'm going to use examples). You're making the CasinoNights system, which runs various games: BlackJack, Slots and Roulette. Each guest is given a card that is tied to the CasinoNights system and allows them access to all three games. Is that correct so far?

Comment: For the record, it may actually be _quicker_ to keep them in the same database. You can't maintain foreign keys (that you'd need for your user IDs) across databases very well (if at all). What you can do, for organization purposes, is prepend a label to the beginning of your game-specific tables (blackjack_games, blackjack_hands, etc.)

Comment: chris: bingo on 1st comment. 2nd statement: definitely quicker. at one time, Blackjack might be too many users, thus Management side has the concern there might be a need to segregate out. my concern is how to handle the "four part naming convention" in sproc, since almost all the developer can access the tables directly. Encapsulation might a bit tough in SProc. EF definitely is not my choice since across dbs, and i am scared of MSDTC.